# What's the definition of an "abstract group"?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, terminology, foundations

Here, I found the following two exercises:

> **Problem IV.** Let $G$ be an *abstract group* and let $a$ and $b$ be elements
>   of $G$. Show that the map $L_a$ : $G \to G$ defined by $L_a(x) := a\star x$ is a
>   bijection. You may find it useful to recall that, given $a$ and $b$ in $G$, the
>   equation $a \star x = b$ has a unique solution in $G$.
>
> **Problem V.** Let $G$ be an *abstract group* with the property that for
>   every $g ∈ G$ we have $g \star g = e$. Show that $G$ is abelian, i.e., that for
>   every $a$ and $b$ in $G$ we have $a \star b = b \star a$.

Now I wonder: What's an "abstract group"? I know what a group is. How is the term "abstract group" defined and why doesn't one just say "group"?

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AbstractGroup.html (It does seem a bit redundant to use the word "abstract" in the problems, however, since the limited information you received about each group forces you to treat them as abstract groups anyway.)

Comment: It's the same thing as "group". It is sometimes used to emphasize that the result can be applied to any "concrete" group, i.e. concrete model of an abstract group. For example cyclic group of order $n$ is abstract with concrete example being $\{z\in\mathbb{C}\ |\ z^n=1\}$. Anyway the notation is confusing and should be avoided IMO.

Comment: I've also seen the terminology used when the author wants to ignore any extra structure on the group. For example, algebraic groups can be thought of as groups with the structure of an affine variety as well. Then it might be the case that two algebraic groups have isomorphic group structure, but this isomorphism may not preserve the structure as varieties as well. So the author may say two groups are isomorphic as $\textit{abstract groups}$, to emphasize they are not necessarily isomorphic as algebraic groups.

Comment: Once upon a time people studied permutation groups, meaning (in modern language) a group equipped with a faithful action on some set. Eventually we learned how to do without the faithful action, and sometimes the term "abstract group" is used to emphasize this.

Comment: I feel the same when people write "let $G$ be a discrete group".

Comment: An object whose sole defining elements are those of a group without further assumptions  (like being matrices, pêrmutations, function products of.., etc.)  just replace "abstract" by "any.".

Comment: @DerekHolt Or "multiplicative group".